# Delete a div box using php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to delete a div box from a .txt file
but it deletes all the file..

**addtodos.php**

```
function getTodos($userID) {
    if (!file_exists("./data/todos/$userID.txt")) {
        file_put_contents("./data/todos/$userID.txt", "", FILE_APPEND);
    }

    $wholeFile = file_get_contents("./data/todos/$userID.txt");
    $allLines = explode(PHP_EOL, $wholeFile);

    for($i = 0; $i < count($allLines) - 1; $i++) {
        $contactValues = explode("|", $allLines[$i]);
        $todos = new stdClass;
        $todos->todosID = trim($contactValues[0]);
        $todos->currentDate = trim($contactValues[1]);
        $todos->text = trim($contactValues[2]);
        $allTodos[] = $todos;
    }

    if(isset($allTodos)) {
        return $allTodos;
    }
}


function deletTodo ($userID, $ID) {
    $todos = getTodos($userID);

    file_put_contents("data/todos/$userID.txt" , "" );

    $ChangeIDs = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($todos); $i++) {
        if($todos[$i]->contactID == $ID) {
            $ChangeIDs = 1;
        }

        else{
        $todosID = $todos[$i]->todosID - $ChangeIDs;
        $todosDate = $todos[$i]->currentDate;
        $todosText = $todos[$i]->text;

        $newContactDetails = $todosID ." | ". $todosDate ." | ". $todosText;
        file_put_contents("data/todos/$userID.txt" , $newContactDetails.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND );
        }
    }
}
```

**deletTodos.php**

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    include "Model/addTodos.php";

    $userID = $_SESSION["userID"];

    $todosID=$_POST["todosID"];
    deletTodo ($userID, $todosID);
    header("location: todos.php");

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**todos.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION["rand"]);
    unset($_SESSION["count"]);

    include "Model/user.php";
    include "Model/addTodos.php";

    if(isset($_SESSION["userID"]) == false) {
        header("Location: login.php");
    }
    $userID = $_SESSION["userID"];
    $allUsers = getUsers();
    $userName = $allUsers[$userID-1]->username;
    $userPoints = $allUsers[$userID-1]->points;

    $todos = getTodos($userID);
    $NextTodosId = getNextTodosId($userID);

    date_default_timezone_set("asia/jerusalem");
    $date = date("F j, Y, g:i a");


    if(isset($_POST["todos"])) {

        // Validation......

        $text = $_POST["todos"];
        $contact2Save = "$NextTodosId | $date | $text" . PHP_EOL;
        file_put_contents("Data/todos/$userID.txt", $contact2Save, FILE_APPEND);

        header("Location: todos.php");
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="header">
        <div class="leftHeader">
            <a href="index.php">Home</a> | 
            <a href="chat.php">Chat</a> | 
            <a href="numGuess.php">Guessing Game</a> | 
            <a href="calc.php">Calculator</a> | 
            <a href="todos.php">Todos</a>
        </div>
        <div class="rightHeader">
            <h3>
                Hello <?php echo"<div class=\"userName\">$userName ($userPoints points)</div>"; ?>
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="todosbox2">
            <form method="POST" action="todos.php">
                <input type="text" name="todos" class="todos" placeholder="Enter new mission">
                <input type="submit" value="Add" class="numGuessSubmit" name="submitCalculate">
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="todosbox">
                <?php
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($todos); $i++) {
                    $todosID = $todos[$i]->todosID;
                    $todosDate = $todos[$i]->currentDate;
                    $todosText = $todos[$i]->text;


                    echo "<div class=\"todo1\">
                                &lt$todosDate&gt;<br/>
                                <h3><b>$todosText</b></h3><br/>
                                <a href=\"doneTodos.php\">Done</a> | 
                                <a href=\"deletTodos.php?todosID=$todosID\">Delete</a>
                            </div>";
                    }

                ?>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**my text file:**

1 | July 13, 2014, 7:26 pm | asdsd
2 | July 13, 2014, 7:39 pm | asdasd
3 | July 13, 2014, 7:40 pm | asda

Answer (score 0):

```
file_put_contents("data/todos/$userID.txt" , "" );
```

This line in apptodos.php in your function deletTodo is responsible for your empty file. Comment or delete that line.

If you want to delete a line you have to get your txt-file like in "function getTodos($userID)" and iterate through every line. While iterating you can check for your "$todosID". When you find a line with ID just jump to the next line so you don't read and save it. At the end of the file use your file_put_content and write it all back to your txt-file.

Maybe there is a chance that you can choose a database for this. It is much more easier to work with a database then to use a filesystem.

**Untested example:**

```
function deletTodo ($userID, $todosID) {
    $wholeFile = file_get_contents("./data/todos/$userID.txt");
    $allLines = explode(PHP_EOL, $wholeFile);
    $allTodos = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < count($allLines) - 1; $i++) {
        $contactValues = explode("|", $allLines[$i]);
        $todos = new stdClass;
        if (trim($contactValues[0]) == $todosID) 
          continue;
        $todos->todosID = trim($contactValues[0]);
        $todos->currentDate = trim($contactValues[1]);
        $todos->text = trim($contactValues[2]);
        $allTodos[] = $todos;
    }

    file_put_contents("data/todos/$userID.txt" ,  print_r($allTodos, true));
}
```

Comment: Ok, my fault. Then first try to debug that last line with "$newContactDetails" before you use file_put_content. What are the values in there?

Comment: $newContactDetails = $todosID ." | ". $todosDate ." | ". $todosText;
  file_put_contents("data/todos/$userID.txt" , $newContactDetails.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND );

Comment: I fixed my last line. Otherwise you would write an array to your file. Now file_put_contents will write your whole list into your txt-file.

Comment: it still delete the whole file

Comment: Please add this line in your getTodos()  
`$newContactDetails = $todosID ." | ". $todosDate ." | ". $todosText;  
print_r($newContactDetails);  
file_put_contents("data/todos/$userID.txt" , $newContactDetails.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND );`  
  
But you also need to disable for this that line:  
`//header("location: todos.php");`  
  
Otherwise you won't see the output.